# Listen for spring boot embedded tomcat failure

Tags: spring-boot

If the embedded tomcat instance within spring-boot fails (port already in use for example). The spring boot application is unaware. The TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer adds connectors using "StandardSerice" which just catches the exception and logs it. StandardService is a tomcat class and so can't be changed within the scope of spring-boot.

Does anyone have a solution to perhaps listen for tomcat lifecycle events to catch this failure within the spring application and exit?

This is using spring boot 1.1.4. The same behaviour is seen either by launching the Main class of the application from eclipse or by running the executable jar built using the spring-boot maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of Spring Boot you're using, or how you're running your application which makes it very hard to provide a definitive answer.

In 1.1.4.RELEASE running with `java -jar`, `gradle bootRun` or `mvn spring-boot:run` should fail and exit in the event of a port clash. If you're running your application directly in your IDE then there's a [known problem](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1232) that meant the application wouldn't exit. It's fixed in the latest 1.1.5 snapshots.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the question stating the version and the running mechanism

Comment: I'd give 1.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT a go (it's available from the repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot Maven repository). As described above, it should fix the problem when you launch the main class in Eclipse. There's a chance that it'll also fix the problem when running the executable jar – as you can see in the issue I linked to (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1232) there was some surprise that the behaviour varied depending on how the app was launched.